# Using JDBCBatchItemWriter for calling an Oracle Procedure gets EmptyResultDataAccessException

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Java based configuration for my Spring Batch. I am calling a stored procedure "writer.setSql("call proc (:_name)");"
The data is getting inserted through the procedure. However, I am getting exception " <<<<<<<<<

Thanks

Note: I am skipping "Exception.class" in my step.

Comment: Please add the stack trace from the error. Also, it's generally unwise to catch/skip all exceptions.

Comment: True. I am running trial so catching all Exceptions to know what all is valid to be skipped for the scenario. However, for skip or no skip, I see a single argument in the config. What if I want to skip more than one?. w.r.t issue I have updated the findings. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The issue is due to the assertion of updates from the JDBCBatchItemWriter. The proc does not return the no.of rows affected like a sql statement. The java code throws the Exception of the count of updates is 0. The solution to the problem stated above is to setAssertUpdates to False " writer.setAssertUpdates(false)".
However, the question still remains on the best writer to use to execute DB objects like procedure or functions and how transactions should be managed.

Refer to the source code from the url below:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.java

Answer (score 2):

I use Java Configuration. Set the writer to avoid 'assert updates' does the job.

```
writer.setAssertUpdates(false);
```